# Need to run rules against messages arriving in JMS Queue

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, rule-engine, mq, complex-event-processing

I have a JMS Queue which will be flooded with event messages from another system. I need to write a program/component which reads the messages and compares the event data against set of rules. Multiple rules can match a message from JMS. If they match, the system should be able to send notifications.

Example:
JMS Queue will be flooded with a strings.
Users of this system are interested in specific type of strings.
User1 will create a rule - "String that contains no special chars"
User2 will create a rule - "String with only capital letters"
and so on...
I should design a system which consumes the strings from the JMS, check the string against all rules, and alert the respective user that a string matching his rule has arrived.

Some considerations :
Hundreds of users.
Each user can create hundreds of rules.
Totally thousands of rules need to be run for a single string from JMS.
So, the comparison needs to be extremely fast.
Also, the users are allowed to create more rules while the system is running.

Which framework will help me achieve this?